# iReport 4.7.1. doesn't display interior of fields that use Calibri font

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

When using the *Calibri* font the IDE doesn't show the text associated to that field like $F{FIELD_A}, no matter how much height (or width) that field has. The IDE also crashed a couple of times when i selected all fields and i tried to select another font. I don't know where to find the crash log file.

I wanted to post images, but I'm new to the forum and it seems I don't have the right to.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also unexplicable errors when using Calibri, apparently it's a java bug specific to this font [as reported here](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11014777)

Comment: Thank you. I've uninstalled java 7u21(now using java 7u12) and now the font _Calibri_ displays correctly in iReport 4.7.1

Comment: I have also tried out java 7u25(jdk) and it seems to work just fine. Maybe they corrected the bug.